# Fade animation in Google Map default tile

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

How to make fade animation when new new default tile loads?

For eg: if zoomed in, how to fade out the previous tile (of low zoom) and fade in new tile(of high zoom)?

Another eg: If a double tap on some position, it should fade out the tile and fade in the new higher zoom level tile. Currently, it is displaying without fading animation.

Comment: i have neutralized; happy :) and also please elaborate the scenerio... if i read i didn't understand what u want

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: [Adding Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#add) seems to be your best option. When you provide a `TilesOverlayOption`, `fadeIn` is an option you can set.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly are you asking for lets say we are at zoom level 10, then we zoom in to 11 and you want the level 10 tiles to stay in place and have the zoom 11 tiles fade in over the zoom 10 tiles and have the zoom 10 tiles fade out after?

Comment: @ChrisBrasino yes